# What was the rationale for making realloc(ptr, 0) have UB in C23

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, memory-management

This is the first breaking change that C made, which was making `realloc(ptr, 0)` have UB instead of being roughly equivalent to `free(ptr)`.

C has been known to be hesitant to making 'breaking' changes such as being extra careful to add `_Ugly` keywords that will not conflict with existing codebases.

So why did they see it necessary to undefine `realloc(ptr, 0)`? What problems did requiring that to have defined behavior cause?

Comment: Some info here https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2464.pdf

Comment: Preivously, the behavior of realloc(ptr, 0) was implementation defined -- it was NOT "generally" equivalent to free(ptr).  As to why they decided to make it undefined rather than implementation defined, it is not clear.

Comment: Also worth reading https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2438.htm

Answer (score 3):

Previously, `realloc(ptr, 0)` was implementation-defined. As far as portable programming is concerned, there's little operational difference between implementation-defined behavior and undefined behavior.

First of all, a portable program can't depend on a specific behavior. Not all implementations would treat `realloc(ptr, 0)` like `free(ptr)`, so you could get memory leaks with some implementations.

Second, an implementation is permitted to provide a definition of the behavior of something that the standard says is undefined. So if you're writing a program that's targeted to a particular implementation, you can take advantage of its definition of this situation.